# What is the animated battery shaped icon in Visual Studio 2012's status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have this icon in the status bar of my VS2012 and is constantly animating like a battery being charged. It does not have a tooltip. Does anybody know what it is indicating?

[image]

Comment: I don't. That looks like a screenshot taken whilst debugging. Does it *only* show up when debugging, or is it always present? What sort of project is this? Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: It is always there. I have Xamarin for VS installed.